# Residence Permit, Leaving country well in time: Impact on future travel?

Tags: visas, schengen, residency

Let's say you had a residence permit of one of the Schengen countries and you moved there and you left the country for your home country well before its expiry date because you realized you could not live there for a long duration due to your personal situation at that time and had to go back.

Does that have any good/bad impact on your application if you ever apply again to move to that country? (it's been a few years) Or at least does it have a good/bad impact if you apply for a tourist visa with your family?

**Edit**

There were no requirements to state any change in address, and there were none. I stayed at the location I pre booked before travelling to that country and listed the location on the visa application. From there i just took a train to airport and got on a flight back home when i had to. Though i did not report to them to revoke the permit as I was under rights to go back there within the said period but unfortunately life doesn't always work as planned. And yep no pending leases or invoices whatsoever.

I would also like to mention there were no financial constraints at that time and if i decide to apply again i will still be able to provide proofs of adequate financial resources which are more than enough to meet the listed financial requirements by that country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a borderline opinion question...

**Good impact**: you have a history of performance which adds credibility to subsequent applications.  This would be be enhanced if you notified the member state advising them that your permit should be voluntarily revoked.  They love stuff like that and they will trust you more.

**Bad impact**: you were unable to complete the purpose of your stay, in many cases this is caused by unstable personal circumstances or your financial situation was not as strong as previously claimed. This decreases your credibility.  They will look at your stuff more carefully next time.

Residence permits are not issued under Schengen regulations like visitor visas are, but by the individual member states and you did not identify which state issued your permit.  If the member state needed you to report a change in circumstances or change of address, then you could be delinquent on that count.  Hopefully you acquitted yourself of any reporting requirements (and also left no open invoices or abandoned leases).

If you are planning to apply for a Schengen that includes your family, you would want to take extra care to explain everything carefully and include an audit trail that supports your explanation.  A residence permit followed by a Schengen for the whole family can raise alarm bells.

## Update

You edited to provide more detail on your specific case.  Based on what you wrote, you'll be fine.  I see no apparent problems in obtaining a Schengen with the remaining caveat that extra care is needed when a family is applying as visitors subsequent to a residence permit.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, you can add that material to your question to help focus it better and I can try to edit the answer.  If so, please edit the question, It wouldn't be fair to others wanting to write an answer because they may not see these comments and have all the info.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, ok try it now...